# how to get input in jscript (for windows apps)?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on this application (.exe) for windows with javascript that calculates the sum of two numbers. But i need to know how to get a user input in javascript for windows.

```
var a= /*code for user input*/;
var b= /*code for user input*/;

var c=a+b;
print(c);
```

Comment: That depends entirely on what tech you're using to create Windows .exes with JavaScript.

Comment: @BipBip I tried that but it doesn't work on windows.

Comment: Why aren't you using form elements?

Comment: More detail is needed here.

Comment: @Juhana I'm using the javascript compiler jsc.exe from .net framework along with cmd to compile my programs.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Because im not using html.

Comment: Try visiting http://www.phpied.com/make-your-javascript-a-windows-exe/ for more clarity.

Comment: By windows i mean windows apps.

Comment: @rockerorigami What are you using for your UI then?

Comment: @JonathanSampson im using notepad

Comment: This type  of "js" is like c#

Comment: @rockerorigami Forms are not unique to HTML; your suggested answer below is *using forms*. Also, it appears as though you're using JScript **.NET**, rather than JScript, which is Microsoft's implementation of the ECMAScript standard, and thus practically identical to JavaScript. JScript .NET is different in numerous ways. Also, why did you tag this with [tag:javascript]? You're throwing me off my game too early in the morning :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this:

```
import System;
import System.Drawing;
import Accessibility;
import System.Windows.Forms;

class EventTestForm extends Form
{
  var btn : Button;
  var tbx : TextBox;
  var tbx2 : TextBox;
  var equ;
  var equ2;
  function EventTestForm()
  {
    tbx = new TextBox;
    tbx2 = new TextBox;
    tbx.Top = 21;
    btn = new Button;
    btn.Top=42;

    btn.Text = "Fire Event";
    Controls.Add(btn);
    Controls.Add(tbx);
    Controls.Add(tbx2);
       // Connect the function to the event.
    btn.add_Click(ButtonEventHandler1);
  }

  // Add an event handler to respond to the Click event raised
  // by the Button control.
  function ButtonEventHandler1(sender, e : EventArgs)
  {
    equ = Convert.ToInt32(tbx.Text);
    equ=int.Parse(tbx.Text);
    equ2 = Convert.ToInt32(tbx2.Text);
    equ2=int.Parse(tbx2.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(equ+equ2);
  }
}

Application.Run(new EventTestForm);
```

Steps to compile:

```
1.go to you .net framework folder.
2.search for jsc.exe.
3.add its location to your environmental variable "path".
4.save this code as calc.js
5.open cmd and goto the folder where calc.js is located.
6.type jsc calc.js
7.run calc.exe.
```

Answer (score -2):

The `prompt` keyword is what you're looking for.

```
var a = prompt("A:");
var b = prompt("B:");

print(a + b);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but that works on html. I'm looking for windows.